# One class data use in another class data C#

Tags: c#

I have following two class which is already inherited to `XYZ`

**Country Class**

```
public class country_master : XYZ
{
        private string _id;

        public string id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }
        private string _country_code;

        public string country_code
        {
            get { return _country_code; }
            set { _country_code = value; }
        }


        private string _country_name;

        public string country_name
        {
            get { return _country_name; }
            set { _country_name = value; }
        }
}
```

**State Class**

```
public class state_master: XYZ
{
        private string _id;

        public string id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }
        private string _state_code;

        public string state_code
        {
            get { return _state_code; }
            set { _state_code= value; }
        }


        private string _state_name;

        public string state_name
        {
            get { return _state_name; }
            set { _state_name= value; }
        }
}
```

- Now, I want to use `country_name` in my `state_master` class how it is possible?

Thank You.

Comment: How do you want to use it? In a method? Have a unique instance per instance of the `state_master`?

Comment: in state_master Method.

Comment: Bro, the class `state_master` can use only  `XYE` properties, if you wanna use `country_name` you can have an instanace of `country_master` as a property in your `state_master` class, or maybe move `country_name` to `XYZ` class.

Comment: XYZ is use because of another property is used.

Comment: any other way like interface???

Comment: an interface would be only a contract that both have to adhere to. you would still need to implement the property in both classes, and each object would have it's own value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a variable of type `country_master` in your `state_master` class.
Then you can access the property `country_name`.

Crossinheritance is not possible unfortunately. (If you have a brother you cannot just use his hands, although you inherit from the same parent. You would need your brother in person.)

Example:

```
public class state_master: XYZ
{
    private country_master _cm;

    public country_master cm
    {
        get { return _cm; }
        set { _cm = value; }
    }

    public void state_method()
    {
        this.cm = new country_master();
        this.cm.country_name;
    }

}
```

Another possibility would be of course to pass the variable from outside at the call to the method

```
public void state_method(string country_name)
{
    // use country name
}
```

calling site:

```
state_master sm = new state_master();
country_master csm = new country_master();

sm.state_method(cm.countr_name);
```

(Now you are asking your brother to lend you a hand)

Answer (score 2):

There's more than one way to skin a cat.

You can create a new instance of country_master:

```
public class state_master: XYZ
{
    private country_master CountryMaster;
    // Class constructor
    public state_master()
    {
        CountryMaster = new country_master();
    }

    private string _id;
    ...
```

or pass an existing instance of country_master to the constructor:

```
public class state_master: XYZ
{
    private country_master CountryMaster;
    // Class constructor
    public state_master(country_master cm)
    {
        CountryMaster = cm;
    }

    private string _id;
    ...
```

and call it with

```
country_master MyCountry = new country_master();
state_master MyState = new state_master(MyCountry);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code so that state_master inherit country_master

```
public class state_master: country_master
```

Comment: public class state_master : XYZ is compulsory  write because of XYZ properties and its methods used in the state_master class.

Comment: Since country_master  inherits  XYZ, then  state_master  would inherits both XYZ and country_master

Comment: @Ehsan.Saradar  have you tried this out? to inherit from 2 base classes?

Comment: yes, state_master inherits country_master  and country_master  inherits XYZ